# Implement Infinite scroll in ag-grid Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid, infinite-scroll

I am trying to implement infinite scroll in ag-grid . I could see many examples which makes request to api and gets the next set of data . But my scenario is different.  On first api call itself I will get entire data , just that I have to show first 20 records on load , then when user scrolls and reaches the bottom of table I have to load the grid with next 20 records . Can someone tell me is it something achievable and guide me in possible .

Comment: did you try this? `https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/scrolling-performance/#8-debounce-vertical-scroll`

Comment: @pinaki There is not much explanation added to it ..  can you please explain

Answer (score 0):

If you have your entire set of data then you should be able to follow this example as that too loads all the data but only gives the data a set amount of rows at a time.

So you will need to implement the IDataSource interface a bit like this.

```
fetch('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then(function (data) {
    const dataSource: IDatasource = {
      rowCount: undefined, // behave as infinite scroll

      getRows: function (params: IGetRowsParams) {
        console.log('asking for ' + params.startRow + ' to ' + params.endRow);

          // take a slice of the total rows
          const rowsThisPage = data.slice(params.startRow, params.endRow);
          // if on or after the last page, work out the last row.
          let lastRow = -1;
          if (data.length <= params.endRow) {
            lastRow = data.length;
          }
          // call the success callback
          params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
      },
    };

    gridOptions.api!.setDatasource(dataSource);
  });
```